# Weekly forecasts when some predictors are monthly

Tags: forecasting, seasonality

I would like to forecast at the weekly level, but some of the predictors are at the monthly level. The only way I can think to approach this problem is to divide the monthly total by the number of weeks. What are some possible alternatives?

Comment: There is no need to do that. The coefficients will adjust any way. What you're blurring over is that weeks (however defined) often overlap months any way.

Comment: I have recently dealt with similar data set. One option could be to fit a curve(line) and estimate it. You could use Excel to fit a "Trend Line" which would give the equation of curve (need to tick the box) and r-square (need to tick the box).

Comment: so you are saying that If the value for a month is `10` then I just state that `10` is the value of the predictor for each week? In other words, I am simply repeating the value?

Comment: Implication is that the OP has other predictors at different scales. If so, this is some distance from what is needed. Using Excel doesn't really count as specifying a statistical method: more detail is needed.

Comment: Quite so, except that weeks overlapping months are awkward.

Comment: not trying to do stat analysis using Excel, simply to get a weekly figures for the data set instead of dividing a monthly figure by 4?